# Firefox cannot find PATCH in access-control-allow-methods

Tags: http, firefox, cors, fastapi

Preflight response returns headers

```
server: uvicorn
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
access-control-max-age: 600
access-control-allow-headers: Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type
content-length: 2
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

for request with headers

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Access-Control-Request-Method: PATCH
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
Origin: http://localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```

But Firefox (102.0) rejects this with reason `CORS Method Not Found`.

`POST` and `DELETE` methods work fine, only `PATCH` is rejected. In Chrome, this request passes without problems.

In FastAPI, I have a middleware configured as following:

```py
    middleware=[Middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=["*"], allow_methods=["*"])],
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be? I also don't send any content/data in this `PATCH` request, I don't know if that's important.

Comment: Yes, patch requests should contain a body (and the response should as well). See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH

Comment: Why should the request contain the body though? I'm using `PATCH /resource/reset` to modify a resource, there is no need for the body. I see no other appropriate method to use from those, that should not contain a body. Also, when I added a body to the request, result is still the same.

Comment: Please post the error message from Firefox.

Comment: Error message: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8081/resource/.../reset. (Reason: Did not find method in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’).`

Comment: I have the same problem with delete request, did you fixed that? :(